# Knockout Event handlers within nested View Models

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have multiple UI components that needs a navigation menu. I am trying to create a MenuItem viewModel that other viewModels can use.

The idea is similar to the [Knockout Webmail Example](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/WebmailExampleStandalone.html).

For example, a "Window" viewModel can have an array of "MenuItems". A MenuItem contains all the behavioral functionality (hover & active states).

While hover & active states are pretty standard in my use case, each MenuItem needs to trigger a click handler individually.

It will be ideal if I can attach event callbacks within the MenuItem viewModel so that parent viewModels can handle each menuItem's click event.

I can define the click handlers in the parent viewModel, **but how do I reference each MenuItem's click handler in a foreach template binding?**

I am still experimenting and created an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonnathan/ChK43/). I am really not too happy with the markup right now either as the data-bindings are too verbose.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `ko.contextFor(this)`.

Have a look [Ko unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of unobtrusive event handlers. But wouldn't that make jQuery a dependency? No way to handle the events within the KO viewModel?

Comment: Well you can write a custom binding. In this [Article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/event-delegation-in-knockoutjs.html) you can get an idea of how to do it. They are using Jquery templates to get access to the actual object clicked by the user, but you can acces to it using ko.contextFor

Comment: You understood my last comment more than I did, apparently. Thank you for the link to the Article :-)